# Android how to get feeds from a .aspx feed?

Tags: android, rss, feed

when i try to read from a .aspx feed, the app gives me a error. 
I think is the XmlParser file that i use. Works fine with .xml feeds, but when i try to use it to read that .aspx feed just give a error.

Any idea to help ?

Thank you.

The error message is: 05-16 13:30:31.296: E/Error:(1117): PI must not start with xml (position:unknown xm@1:7 in java.io.StringReader@2fe98718)

Code of XmlParser file

```
// constructor
public XMLParser() {

}

/**
 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
 * @param url string
 * */
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

/**
 * Getting XML DOM element
 * @param XML string
 * */
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}



/** Getting node value
  * @param elem element
  */
 public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node child;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return child.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 /**
  * Getting node value
  * @param Element node
  * @param key string
  * */
 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
```

}

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Hi Ancantus, i have edited the problem with the error message of the console. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, from my searches. It looks to be an error with BOM encoding. Take a look at these 2 solutions and see if they solve your problem.

[UTF-8 byte-order-mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938231/xml-pull-parser-error-when-declaration-present)

[Discard the xml header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988145/why-does-this-code-keep-triggering-the-saxparseexception)